# Does bleach react with disinfectants containing quaternary ammonium salts?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

My mom went nuts when we pulled up the laminate to discover mold growing on the subfloor. She sprayed bleach all over it while I was at the store buying [Mold Armor mold remover and disinfectant](http://www.moldarmor.com/product/mold-remover-disinfectant), and found out from calling poison control that this product should not be mixed with bleach. The operator was not sure what I could do to make it so it was safe to apply the mold remover.

Can anyone tell me if when bleach dries, the chemical reaction will be mitigated? I just want to clean my house without killing everyone. The surface is porous, and made of wood/particle board.

Comment: "I just want to clean my house without killing everyone"... Don't we all :)

Answer (score 3):

**Calling poison control first was the best thing you could do! Thumbs up!**

Please note that we're usually reluctant to give medical advice - we don't want to get you or anyone in your house get killed or harmed either.

You might want to call poison control again and/or send them the [safety data sheet](http://www.moldarmor.com/uploads/general/FG550_SDS-86-M.pdf) of the product.

The following is just additional information to give you some direction on why it is **probably** safe to use the mold remover on the floor previously treated with bleach.

The [College of Veterinary Medicine at Cornell University](http://www.sheltermedicine.vet.cornell.edu/) has published [Guidelines for the Use of Bleach](http://www.sheltermedicine.vet.cornell.edu/resources/documents/UsingBleach.pdf). According to this document,

> Bleach can safely be mixed with quaternary ammonium compounds that contain detergents, such as A-33 and Roccal to create a single solution with both cleaning and disinfecting properties.

So, I'd dare to say that the combined use, as well as subsequent treatment of the floor is safe, but if I were you, I would search again confirmation with official poison control rather than trusting some guy from the internet ;-)